# Moving a zoomed image with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to do something like [this](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/jquery-image-panning/demo/demo.html)

But I do not know how to start with it, tried zooming the image with `scale` function in CSS but it refuses to use `translate`, so my question now is how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have a look at this site I am sure it will solve you issue.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.photo').zoom({url: 'photo-big.jpg'});
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.photo').zoom({
    url: 'photo-big.jpg', 
    callback: function(){
      $(this).colorbox({href: this.src});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That's what I was searching for! Thanks sir.